# Scala: How to do pattern matching on type of the instance that method is called on?

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I've tried looking through the similar questions without finding the answer, and I cannot find anything through google either for some reason.

Let's say I have the following List type:

```
sealed abstract class CustomList[T]
case class Nil[T]() extends CustomList[T]
case class Cons[T](head: T, tail: CustomList[T]) extends CustomList[T]
```

Now I want to define a map method on this list type using pattern matching, e.g. like this:

```
def map[T1, T2](list: CustomList[T1], func: T1 => T2): CustomList[T2] = list match {
  case Nil() => Nil()
  case Cons(head, tail) => Cons(func(head), map(tail, func))
}
```

This works if I just declare on some utility object and pass the list as a parameter, like this:

```
val list = Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil())))
val mapped = CustomList.map(list, (x: Int) => x * x)
```

But what I want is to have it as a method on the class instance itself, so I can do something like this:

```
val list = Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil())))
val mapped = list.map((x: Int) => x * 2)
```

So is there a way I can do pattern matching on the list that i call .map() on, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Maybe what you want is: `def map[U](func: T => U): CustomList[U] = this match {` ? inside the body of the  **CustomList** trait / abstract class?

Comment: Oh so I can use 'this' to refer to the instance itself?

Comment: Yeah, that is the point of `this` on **Scala** and many other programming languages.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I've only tried using the self keyword, which apparently means something entirely different. Case closed :D

Comment: There is no `self` keyword on **Scala**. You can do this: `sealed abstract class CustomList[T] { self => ` in which case, `self` becomes an alias to `this` and should work.

Comment: It might be important to note that matching on the own instance is usually bad practice and should be avoided. In your case you should define an abstract method `map` and use two different implementations for the two subclasses. That's how it's done with the real list, too.

Comment: @MarkusAppel why it is a bad practice? I have done it plenty of times without problems. The real list implementation isn't really to be followed on normal code, it makes many things to improve performance. For example, their `tail` is a **var** thus it is mutable under the hood.

Comment: @MarkusAppel See examples of `this match` in standard library https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/util/Either.scala#L188

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I can imagine two arguments about preferring subtyping polymorphism over pattern matching. Firstly, in a situation when new classes are added more often than new methods ([see](https://medium.com/better-programming/pattern-matching-vs-polymorphism-ce0441fbfcda), good old [expression problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem)). Secondly, **maybe** dynamic dispatch can work sometimes [faster](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8677308) than pattern matching.

Comment: @DmytroMitin yeah I know dynamic dispatch may be faster, also I agree with the first statement. However, that one doesn't really apply to well defined **ADTs** like lists. And my point wasn't that doing what Markus suggested was bad, just that doing the pattern match isn't a bad practice.